# what can cause connection to a port in the same node refused?

Tags: networking, akka, apache-spark

Got an EndpointWriter error:

14/10/30 23:12:29 ERROR EndpointWriter: AssociationError [akka.tcp://sparkWorker@node001:35249] -> [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@node001:7088]: Error [Association failed with [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@node001:7088]] [
akka.remote.EndpointAssociationException: Association failed with [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@node001:7088]
Caused by: akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport$$anonfun$associate$1$$anon$2: Connection refused: node001/10.69.144.56:7088

the node001 and 10.69.144.56 are both the node itself. my understanding is that akka was trying to connect to a port in local but got rejected. The executor port was fixed to be '7087'.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The usual reason for connection refused is that there is nothing listening on the port. If the port that executor is listening on is 7087, akka is trying to make a connection to port 7088 and there's probably nothing listening there. Check your code or configuration to see if you got 7088 instead of 7087.